How would you best translate "tis but a flesh wound" to Latin
So it's a "Monty Python" line by the Black Knight as he gets his arms and legs hacked off and in ridiculous defiance as a response shouts "it is just a flesh wound" as in it was minor injury, nothing at all. A friends best suggestion was "Est solum, leve vulnus".
